# Vectorizing diff function on lags in R

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I would like to make a function that does the following:

```
c <- rnorm(100)
n <- 10
sum.diff<- integer(n)

for (k in 1:n) {
   sum.diff[k] <- sum(diff(c, lag=k))
}
```

through vectorization rather than looping. Specifically, I want to send in one vector (here 'c'), and a vector of lag values (here '1:n'), and get out the sum of the k-th differences in the k-th entry of the output vector (here 'sum.lags').

For example, `c <- 1:100` with `n <- 10` should yield:

`99
196
291
...
900`

which corresponds to:

`sum(diff(1:100,lag=1))
sum(diff(1:100,lag=2))
sum(diff(1:100,lag=3))
...
sum(diff(1:100,lag=10))`

Any ideas?

Comment: I can think of a way to do it with `sapply` vice the `for` loop, but it isn't really vectorized nor is it faster (in fact, a little slower). The problem with vectorizing this one is that you are dealing with different quantities of numbers with each iteration. Are you hoping to vectorize because your production code is dealing with considerably larger datasets? If so, I'd recommend `compiler::cmpfun` or, even better, Rcpp.

Comment: It is a larger dataset (and thus very slow), but it is for a somewhat specific issue that may not be something worth investing that much time in. It is somewhat difficult to justify rpp (I have never used it, but have been dying to learn it, although I do have C++ experience), but I will check out both. If nothing else, it could serve as a way to get acquainted with things I should know. Thanks!

Comment: Rcpp with "sugar" and similar R-like syntax is not hard to learn. If you already have some c++ experience then learning Rcpp will probably be much easier than you imagine. (BTW: coding "best practices" generally discourage using `c` as a variable name ... it works, but ...)

Comment: Thanks, that is encouraging. Yeah, I was only using `c` for this question. The actual variable name in my code is `ln.pre.grid`, but thanks :)

Comment: Having trouble understanding the meaning of "get out the sum of the lags in the k-th entry of the output vector". The code is obviously incorrect and not really helpful. Please specify a small reproducible dataset and the "correct" answer.

Comment: Sorry, edited to reflect what I actually wanted (code was accurate, wording not) and added a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` implemitation (should be slightly faster than your code on big data sets)

```
a <- 1:100
b <- 1:10
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(b)[, Res := sum(diff(a, b)), by = b]
DT

# b Res
# 1:  1  99
# 2:  2 196
# 3:  3 291
# 4:  4 384
# 5:  5 475
# 6:  6 564
# 7:  7 651
# 8:  8 736
# 9:  9 819
# 10: 10 900
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it was mentioned in the comments about performance and C/C++, here is a way using `.Call` that seems valid:

```
library(inline)

ff = cfunction(sig = c(R_x = "numeric", R_lag = "integer"), body = '
   SEXP x, lag, ans;
   PROTECT(x = coerceVector(R_x, REALSXP));
   PROTECT(lag = coerceVector(R_lag, INTSXP));
   PROTECT(ans = allocVector(REALSXP, LENGTH(lag)));

   double *px = REAL(x), *pans = REAL(ans);
   memset(pans, 0, sizeof(double)*LENGTH(ans));
   R_len_t *plag = INTEGER(lag);

   for(int l = 0; l < LENGTH(lag); l++) 
       for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(x) - plag[l]; i++) 
           pans[l] += px[i + plag[l]] - px[i];

   UNPROTECT(3);

   return(ans);
')

ff(1:100, 1:10)
#[1]  99 196 291 384 475 564 651 736 819 900
```

And some benchmarkings:

```
OPff = function(c, n) {
   sum.diff <- integer(n)
   for (k in 1:n) sum.diff[k] <- sum(diff(c, lag = k))
   sum.diff
}

ff2 = function(c, n) unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i) sum(diff(c, lag = i))))

xx = runif(1e4)
l = 1e3

identical(OPff(xx, l), ff(xx, 1:l))
#[1] TRUE
identical(OPff(xx, l), ff2(xx, l))
#[1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OPff(xx, l), ff(xx, 1:l), ff2(xx, l), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# OPff(xx, l) 387.49171 390.43269 407.25796 427.09764 485.97181    10
# ff(xx, 1:l)  37.73505  38.27028  39.10201  41.33271  46.84648    10
#  ff2(xx, l) 384.35098 389.70397 401.51451 423.38513 436.85008    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 sum.diff <- function(c, n) sapply(n, function(k) sum(diff(c, lag = k)))
```

Now run test:

```
 sum.diff(1:100, 1:10)
 ## [1]  99 196 291 384 475 564 651 736 819 900
```

Comment: How is this vectorized or different from a `for` loop

Comment: @David Arenburg, It does not involve indices or explicit looping.

Comment: It's still not vectorized imo, just presented in a nicer syntax

Comment: Ultimately all operations are done by a loop at the lowest level regardless of approach.  Normally vectorization refers to operating on a whole object and not using indices.